# How to organise overflowing config files and folders in the home directory and beyond!

Tags: bash, homebrew, unix, zsh

**The Context:**

I'm a long-time macOS user who has spent many years dabbling here and there with the *nix side of Apple life since the first iteration of OS X (10.0) originally shipped.

Recently, I find myself compelled to dig a little deeper after deciding to embark on a journey of self education in all things scripting/programming/system administration. Thankfully there exist fantastic tools such as Homebrew, amongst others, to make the management of this macOS shadow-land far more straightforward, *but sometimes it's neccessary to work outside of these self-contained ecosystems.*

**The Core Problem:**

- I find myself gathering a large quantity of configuration-related files and folders in my home directory. This unwiedly & miscellaneous collection seems sub-optimal and I'm wondering if the more experienced have some "best practice" guidance for this situation - maybe even a decicated utility or two?
- I'm keenly aware that the ecosystem of *nix software is extremely sensitive to directory/path structure; and minor changes can have major side effects that aren't immediately obvious,resulting in increasingly time-costly troubleshooting and conflict-resolution in the future - particularly when the problem at hand isn't recent and "fresh in the mind".

Any suggestions/pointers/links or path/environment variables welcome - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These tools expect their `.foorc` file to reside in `~` so there is no easy way to "organize" this better (besides not using the `-a` of `ls` so you don't always see them :-)) unless you want to compile everything from a (appropriately) modified source yourself.

Some tools use an environment variable to read their configuration from a custom location. This is tool-specific though, you need to consult the man page to see whether this is an option.

Some people use `git` or similar tools to easily share configurations between systems (and also as a way to have access to old versions), see (among a ton of other sources) [these](https://superuser.com/questions/1037211/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-git-for-configuration-file-version-controlling) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342886/git-best-practice-for-config-files-etc).

<sub>PS: This is a rather broad answer to a broad question. If you want specific advice for a specific tool, please ask a new question including the relevant details</sub>

Comment: Thanks v much, informative collection of views and utilities you've linked to there. On reflection I guess I'm fundamentally annoyed at using such a 'central' directory for storing all manner of *key* files/folders that don't follow any kind of logical 'grouping'. This makes me wonder whether it's possible to design a utility that masks the file system for a set of desginated binaries, such that when they "think" they're looking at ~/.foorc they're actually looking at some other path, designated and managed by said hypothetical utility. Maybe I just download IgnoranceIsBliss.app into .MyBrain.